Model checking and dependently typed languages for formal verification
What are the differences and limitations between model checking and type-checking dependent types for verifying correctness?
If I were to model a state machine in a language like Idris, what can't I verify that a model checker can and vice-versa? I can enforce valid transitions in Idris, but can I prove reachability or that after any sequence of events the system never reaches some invalid state?

Model checkers tend to be better for checking control-flow properties, i.e., about the sequence of events, particularly in the presence of concurrency, threads, etc.
Dependent types tend to be better for checking data-flow properties, i.e., about the values and types that variables can hold, and typically are not used for sophisticated reasoning about which interleaving of control-flow paths are feasible.
None of these are hard-and-fast limitations or boundaries.  They just reflect what the tools are most commonly used for or most naturally suited to.
Model checkers are often applied to a model of the system, rather than the code itself -- but not always.  Dependent types are often applied to the source code itself, rather than a separate model -- but not always.
